# Web of trust assigning level of trust to someone's public key without directly signing it's key

Tags: pgp

[image]

Having this web of trust scheme, I have a question concerning third scenario in which we assign Dharma and Chloe a marginal trust. In case of Dharma the situation is clear, we sign her public key and assign our marginal trust in it. But how physically we can assign a marginal trust in Chloe's public key when we don't sign her key? Am I missing something?

Comment: To be honest, I don't get how to interpret above at all. Do you have a source for this so we can have a look at the context?

Comment: Its GNU Privacy Handbook. Here: https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x334.html

Comment: Ugh, that's one terrible piece of text.